# How do I rewrite the domain in Sharepoint 2010 when "www" is missing in the request path?

Tags: 2010, url, url-rewriting

I need http://example.com/photogallery to be redirected to http://www.example.com/photogallery (adding the "www").  For some reason it always redirects to http://www.example.com/Pages/default.aspx.  I have the following rewrite rule in my web.config:

```
<rule name="Vanity URL" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^photogallery$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/photogallery" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

I've also tried putting the URL match outside of the conditions:

```
<rule name="Vanity URL" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^photogallery$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/photogallery" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

I've also tried a million permutations of regexes, but I feel like there is some default Sharepoint routing to the main default.aspx page that is overriding all of my efforts.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the publishing features enabled in your site collection, you can specify the welcome page (ie the default page that is loaded when someone hits example.com or www.example.com). If you don't have the publishing features enabled, you can set your default home page in Sharepoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to properly configure the Alternate Access Mappings so that both "www" and "no-www" are available as endpoints to your Web Application.

This post might help understanding how that works: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/27/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx

Also make sure that the bindings are created in IIS.
Here's an explanation on this:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools.aspx